# Making a studentscore program with that assigns marks in array to grades

Tags: c#

Hi i am fairly new to C# programming and i need help in making a program that will check the number of students who have scored

A (80 and above)
B (70 and above)
C (60 and above)
D (50 and above)
F (below 50)

but i have an assign array for marks given so i can't change the marks.

```
int[] marks = new []{ 90, 40, 60, 80, 100, 20, 40, 60, 80, 90 };
```

i will then have to output the amount of students that achieve the grades like:

A: Amount of Students that have scored "A".
B: Amount of Students that have scored "B".
and until grade "F" if there is any.

Please ask me anything if my questions are not well stated. I have only learnt the basics of C# like if-else, while loop, for loops but haven't learnt much .Please mind my English as it is not my strongest language.

Comment: This is sound like homework , please show your attempt and ask for a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

The whole program with mostly beginner friendly code.

```
// Initial scores
int[] scores = new int[] { 90, 40, 60, 80, 100, 20, 40, 60, 80, 90 };

// Marks keep track of how many times each mark was given
Dictionary<string, int> marks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// This is a counter, so init every mark count with 0
marks.Add("A", 0);
marks.Add("B", 0);
marks.Add("C", 0);
marks.Add("D", 0);
marks.Add("F", 0);

// Go through all the scores and give marks
foreach(int score in scores)
{
    if(score >= 80)
    {
        marks["A"]++;
    }
    else if(score >= 70)
    {
        marks["B"]++;
    }
    else if(score >= 60)
    {
        marks["C"]++;
    }
    else if(score >= 50)
    {
        marks["D"]++;
    }
    else
    {
        marks["F"]++;
    }
}

// Finally output every mark
Console.WriteLine("A: " + marks["A"]);
Console.WriteLine("B: " + marks["B"]);
Console.WriteLine("C: " + marks["C"]);
Console.WriteLine("D: " + marks["D"]);
Console.WriteLine("F: " + marks["F"]);
```

If you're having trouble understand some of the concepts, check out some tutorials:

Dictionary: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMjt6ywaSow

Foreach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymgp77c2aR0